# swift 3: dismissing VC removes all modal VCs

Tags: xcode, model-view-controller, swift3

So my code presents a vc onto a already modaled vc. so essentially I have 3 VCs on top of each other 1/2/3. However, when I attempt to dismiss VC#3 both 2/3 get dismissed. I tried to use self.presentingvc to dismiss but I still get the same results. Any solutions?

```
    let SearchController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    SearchController.delegate = self
    present(SearchController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can read the Discussion part of the `dismiss(animated:completion:)` method: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss It should help you understand.

Comment: Wait, why are you calling dismiss immediately after presenting, this code can potentially cause troubles. Or are they meant to be in different file?. Also read the documents from the link given by @Larme

Comment: @Larme I read the article however, even when I call searchController.dismiss it still removes all of the views in the stack

Comment: @ShubhamNaik no I meant them to be two separate files that happen at different points in the program

Comment: I was thinking maybe if I presented a navigation controller that the view was attached to it would solve the problem however I keep getting an error saying pushing a navigation controller is not supported

Comment: Yeah you don't push a `navigation controller`, push a `view controller`. `Navigation controller` is there to manage the presentation of *view controllers*. You can print the `navigationcontroller.viewcontrollers` array to see the full stack. Also I'm not sure what view you keep mentioning, I simply ignored that part here, do clarify.